# Flash framework to help with "packager for iPhone"

Tags: iphone, flash, actionscript-3, packager-for-iphone

Are there any Frameworks for Flash (AS3) that are optimised for outputing to iPhone using the [Flash Packager for iPhone](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/packagerforiphone/)?

I have used the "packager for iphone" with some of my flash apps and games, and it work ok. But there is always some things that need changing. There are also some guidelines for creating content and using the packager. You can see some [guidelines here](http://www.yeahbutisitflash.com/?p=986).

Are there any application or game frameworks out there yet, that take this sort of optimisation into account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since GPU acceleration support was added to the FlashPlayer there have been quite a few frameworks and libraries targeted at mobile.

Probably the most popular is the Adobe funded Starling, and Feathers UI frameworks. These are great for building high performance app for iOS and Android.

Comment: There's also Autodesk's Scaleform

Comment: To clarify, Autodesk promises that their product has the best performance out there and that it also integrates with native engines if needed.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think anything exists so far. The project was suspended for a while (when Apple was not allowing to use anything but C++/Objective C for its devices) - but now it's back to life, so expect something to come.